# blank lines at the top of source code page

Tags: php

I am running into a weird issue, a php file which return a valid JSON except that it output a ton of blank lines at the very top of the file, so if the real output contains 300 lines of code, what I get is 300 + 500 blank lines at the beginning.

Please not that these blank lines are visible only when I show the source code of the page in my browser. How to get rid of that?

Comment: Look for the code that generates those empty lines and remove them.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the sourcecode from anyway? Seems like you have some hidden symbols there.

Comment: did you check that somewhere prior to echoing json there is no other echoing going on? If you cant find the reason for it, you can use ob_start(); at beginning of your landing script and call ob_end_clean(); just before you echo json - that should trap all output in buffer and then clean buffer

Comment: @Ivan, Thanx a million, please put your comment as answer so I can upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check that somewhere prior to echoing json there is no other echoing going on?

If you cant find the reason for it, you can use `ob_start();` at beginning of your landing script and call `ob_end_clean();` just before you echo json - that should trap all output in buffer and then clean buffer